# Cylinder placed in wedge which inturn is on wedge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

A cylinder of mass m rests in a supporting block as shown. if beta = 60 degree and theta = 30 degree, calculate the maximum acceleration a which the block may be given up the incline so that the cylinder does not lose contact at B. (neglect friction anywhere)

Comment: There are some good question on what physics as at play here, and I am sure the site would be happy to answer those, but Physics SE is not a place to simply get textbook style exercises done for you.